# one single non-scrollable background image for the entire page content

Tags: html, css

I need one single image (`01.jpg`) in the background of all page content, and this image should not be scrollable, while all content should be scrollable over the background.

Here is my try, but something is wrong, it doesn't work. Scrolling down a white area appears as the background (`00.jpg`), probably because `wrap` div is higher than body.

What is the best practice here ?

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
...
</div>

</body>
```

css

```
html{
    background-image:url(backs/00.jpg);
    height:100%;
}
body{
    max-width:1920px;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("imgtop/01.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the `height: 100%` parts. It's giving the elements a constant, limited height: The height of the viewport, not the entire document. (The calculation of the height property happens from the topmost element down, so don't expect a change in a lower-level element to affect a height percentage of an upper element.)

From what I could tell, it worked fine for me without those. If that doesn't work, try changing them to `min-height`.

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

try this css

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

for further detail check this https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score -2):

[How to specify a fixed background image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

If still having issues with body background overlay, can try editing its z values (`z-index: 100;`).

Comment: a) You probably shouldn't just link to an outside site as your entire answer - it doesn't futureproof them. b) He's actually already using `background-attachment: fixed` as that page describes.

Comment: True. w3schools page though so unlikely to go poof soon. Also, he isn't using fixed for the page background, just the div body one.

Comment: also, there's no 'why does it work' in the answer, dropping a link and a few words in an answer is never going to be good

Comment: @nocturnal Just FYI, w3schools is not an "official W3C" page. Bigger companies than that have gone poof before (OR just changed their URL scheme, causing any old links to go to their homepage), and it's resulted in a lot of dead-end google links, which is why SO avoids linking except as a way of supplementing an answer.